# How to simply check if a DateTime column is within 30 days of today?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, entity-framework-4

I have a column in my table called `DateTimeOfBid`, I need to fetch all entities where DateTimeOfBid is within 30 days of today.

I'm using Entity-Framework 4 to access my data.

Here's what I have so far:

```
EFUserAuctionLanceRepository userAuctionLanceRepository = new EFUserAuctionLanceRepository();

var potentialDiscount = userAuctionLanceRepository.FindAllUserAuctionLances()
                                                  .Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId && u.AccountableForShopDiscount == true);

var discount = potentialDiscount.Where(p => p.DateTimeOfLance is within 30 days of today?)
```

How can I write this small query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

and then use the lambda expression

```
p => p.DateTimeOfLance >= today.AddDays(-30) &&
     p.DateTimeOfLance <= today.AddDays(30)
```

EF might need you to do the following, though:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime thirtyDaysAgo = today.AddDays(-30);
DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow = today.AddDays(30);


p => p.DateTimeOfLance >= thirtyDaysAgo &&
     p.DateTimeOfLance <= thirtyDaysFromNow
```

Comment: Since this is executed on the DB you have to pre-calculate both dates, otherwise this won't work

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this....

```
if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).CompareTo(date) > 0)
```